# How to convert sentences using 'has' or 'has been' into questions?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

How to convert sentences using '***has***' or '***has been***' into questions?

For example:

> His uncle has a big car.
>
> She has been working at that company for three years

What are the basic rules for such scenarios?

Answer (score 4):

When *has* is being used as an auxiliary verb, you can simply change *subject has* to *has subject*, e.g.

> Has she been working at that company for three years?

When it's used to denote possession, you usually add an auxiliary *does*:

> Does his uncle have a big car?

Comment: Exactly. It might be added, for the benefit of learners who encounter older literature, that many writers and speakers employed the 'inverted' construction with lexical *HAVE* ("Has his uncle a big car?") well into the twentieth century.

Comment: And in British English, many still do so, though usually with the word _got_: "Has his uncle got a big car?"